# Jasper iReports charts changing Label Expressions

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I am using Jasper iReport to create an .xrml file to create a Jasper report. My file has a 3-D bar chart with multiple series - this is keyed on group_id. I want the label to be "Group "+ group_id. I tried to set this in the Chart details->Data-> Category series tab, but it did not work.The .xrml file directly looks like

```
<labelExpression><![CDATA["Group "+$F{group_id} +"sdf"]]></labelExpression>
```

But this just shows 1,2,3 as labels. How can I append the word "Group" to the label please?

Also I would like to create a label for the y-axis, currently it just shows numbers. How can I do that please?

Attaching my .xrml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="simple_chart" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="30a6fcf0-fa89-4cf5-863d-403bf68304ef">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select count(person_id), name, group_id from group_events group by name, group_id]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="count" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="group_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="32" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="191" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="a4a09404-48bc-4895-9c33-b73fc139a67c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[names]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <summary>
        <band height="383">
            <bar3DChart>
                <chart>
                    <reportElement x="30" y="16" width="515" height="298" uuid="3c938c8e-586f-4a0e-a0b7-3a188ed0fe4b"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{group_id}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA["Group "+$F{group_id} + "sdf"]]></labelExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <bar3DPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </bar3DPlot>
            </bar3DChart>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Please, include the complete jrxml of your chart in the question.

Comment: Its not displaying the label correct?, or are you refereeing to legend?

Comment: Label, not legend. It is not appending the prefix to the label expression.

Comment: Do you see the label? (In my 3d barchart label is not showed), can you post an image....

Comment: Yes I see the label. It just has a number 1,2,3 etc. I can't post an image because the data is proprietary :(

Comment: The label is on top of each bar correct?, you can edit image removing property data....

Comment: I have tried with bar3dChart (and with my library version it will not show labels at all), while with barChart they work as expected (using labelExpression) , that's why I'm asking..